# replacing missing values with average and mode in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 C1      C2       C3
 10      a        b
 10      a        b
 ?       c        c
 ?       ?        b
 10      a        b
 10      ?        ?
```

I want to replace `?` with average and mode wherever applicable

My desired dataframe would be

```
 C1      C2       C3
 10      a        b
 10      a        b
 10      c        c
 10      a        b
 10      a        b
 10      a        b
```

I have tried following in pandas but did not work.

```
 df[df['C1'] == '?'] = df[df['C1' != '?'].mean()
```

Comment: @anky_91 `C1` is numerical variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle numeric and non-numeric columns separately

```
df.replace('?', np.nan, inplace = True)

df['C1'] = df['C1'].astype(float)
df['C1'] = df['C1'].astype(float).fillna(df['C1'].mean())

non_numeric = ['C2', 'C3']
df[non_numeric]=df[non_numeric].fillna(df.mode().iloc[0])

    C1      C2  C3
0   10.0    a   b
1   10.0    a   b
2   10.0    c   c
3   10.0    a   b
4   10.0    a   b
5   10.0    a   b
```

Comment: Could you please explain the role of `iloc[0]` here ?